# Anyone know the name of this tool?

Tags: tools, terminology

Does anyone know the name of this tool?

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this one says "Husky" on the other side...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is a lock nut wrench and are ideal for tightening and removing lock nuts on strainer baskets. Easy to find online by searching for that term; looks like an exact match to me. [image]

[image]

Comment: This is a [good picture](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/e4bb30fd-b3c4-490f-a40e-634e417f0145/svn/husky-plumbing-wrenches-16pl0133-e1_600.jpg) for it in use.

Comment: If you embed the picture in your answer, you should specify its source unless you yourself are the author/photographer.